# Is it possible to browse to the TFS web-portal using a PAT?

Tags: browser, tfs, access-token, portal

I have a tfs test server, and using a test account with a PAT issued by my TFS admin account, I wanted to see if it was possible to browse to the TFS web-portal using the PAT to authenticate.

Using:

```
curl -u Test:57qxqxxfdcvnFAKEthisisfakeFAKE https://tfstest.company.com/tfs/collectionname
```

I get some reasonably sensible html back that seems to indicate that it accepted the authentication.   When I save this html to a file and open it, it displays what I might expect.   I don't get the css, or anything but it appears to be the normal page coming back, without anything the browser would normally get when the html is expressed.

I can also use REST API's by specifying the proper URLs for those API's, and so I conclude that the PAT auth is working as expected.

But is it possible for me to open IE and browse to https://tfstest.company.com/tfs/collectionname, by some means, only using the PAT for auth ?

Thanks.

Comment: I probably should have said "authentication" not "authorization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not able to directly use PAT to browser web portal.

> Personal access tokens (PATs) are **alternate passwords** that you can
>   use to authenticate into Azure DevOps.
>
> Azure DevOps uses enterprise-grade authentication to help protect and
>   secure your data. Clients like Visual Studio and Eclipse (with the
>   Team Explorer Everywhere plug-in) also support Microsoft account and
>   Azure AD authentication.
>
> For non-Microsoft tools that integrate into Azure DevOps but don't
>   support Microsoft account or Azure AD authentication, you must use
>   PATs. Examples include Git, NuGet, or Xcode. To set up PATs for
>   non-Microsoft tools, use Git credential managers or create them
>   manually.

When you access TFS server for the first time through web portal, a Windows Identity dialog box appears. You need to fill in your account credentials and password choose the OK button.